# ng-repeat how to get selected data index from script side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to get the index position of selected data in the script side

```
<table ng-table="testTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in $data">
                <td data-title="data"> 
                    {{data.name}} 
                < /td>
                <td data - title="'Actions'">
                    <button ng-click="test(data)">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

something like that

```
 $scope.test = function(data){
        var x = data.index;
    }
```

I know on the html I could do this

```
<button ng-click="test(data,$index)">Add</button>
```

and pass the $index to the script side, but i'm sure there's other way.

Could have some help here, 
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want another way? that's the standard way to do it.

Comment: An alternative is using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with some predicate on your `data` to find it's index.

Comment: You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function to find the index of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="data in $data" ng-init="data.index = $index;">
      <td data-title="data"> 
          {{data.name}} 
      </td>
      <td data - title="'Actions'">
           <button ng-click="test(data)">Add</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Edit: see working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/87PT7pvIKZNe1DyQ8uUu?p=preview

Comment: I've tried adding ng-init="data.index = $index;"
and tried alert(data.index); on script side, unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to initlize before ng-repeat

```
<table ng-table="testTable" ng-init="$data.index = {}">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in $data">
                    <td data-title="data"> 
                        {{data.name}} 
                    < /td>
                    <td data - title="'Actions'" ng-init="data.index.id= $index">
                        <button ng-click="test(data)">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

$scope.test = function(data){
        var x = data.index.id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider following simple example.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages ">
        <a  ng-click="test($index)">{{ $index }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```